# Rails Devise registration with an additional model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've searched for about an hour now and found an immense amount of questions describing how to add fields to the Devise user model. However I couldn't find any that explain in a clear way how to add one or multiple models to the registration process.

At registration I want the user to fill out an e-mailaddress, password and in addition my client model, company model and address model (so I have all the information the webapplication needs to run properly).

My models are like this

**user.rb**

> ```
> class User < ActiveRecord::Base
>   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
>          :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
>
>   attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :client
>
>   belongs_to :client
> end
> ```

**client.rb**

> ```
> class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
>   attr_accessible :bankaccount, :email, :logo, :mobile, :phone, :website
>
>   has_many :users
>
>   has_one :company
>   has_one :address
>   accepts_nested_attributes_for :company, :address
> end
> ```

I think the only way to do this is to create my own RegistrationsController so I can do `@client = Client.new` and then do this in my view:

> ```
>  <%= f.simple_fields_for @client do |ff| %>
>   <%= f.simple_fields_for :company do |fff| %>
>     <% field_set_tag t(:company) do %>
>       <%= ff.input :name %>
>     <% end %>
>   <% end %>
>   <%= f.simple_fields_for :address do |fff| %>
>     //address inputs
>     <% end %>
>   <% end %>
>
>   <fieldset>
>     <legend><%= t(:other) %></legend>
>     // other inputs
>   </fieldset>
> <% end %>
> ```

The reason I need it to work this way is because I have multiple users who can represent the same client (and thus need access to the same data). My client owns all the data in the application and therefor needs to be created before the application can be used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, it took me about 8 hours but I finally figured out how to make it work (if someone has a better/cleaner way of doing this, please let me know).

First I've created my own `Devise::RegistrationsController` to properly build the resource:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def new
    resource = build_resource({})
    resource.build_client
    resource.client.build_company
    resource.client.build_address
    respond_with resource
  end

end
```

After that I just needed to adjust config/routes.rb to make it work:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "users/registrations" } do
    get '/users/sign_up', :to => 'users/registrations#new'
  end
```

Also I had an error in my devise/registrations/new.html.erb. It should have been `f.simple_fields_for :client` instead of `f.simple_fields_for @client`.

Now it properly creates all the objects for the nested attributes and automatically saves it when saving the resource.